# Screens don't work after shutting off

Tags: 11.10, compiz, monitor

When my screens shut off after the configured amount of time, they don't turn back on again. I have to restart my computer because wiggling my mouse, etc doesn't turn the monitor signals back on. Under what package should I file this bug? I have a dual monitor setup with Nvidia twinview.

Comment: I have an nVidia Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 450] (rev a1). This can by found by running `lspci | grep VGA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what model of Nvivia you have as some of the solutions are different.

The most common solution is to edit the xorg.conf file.
(note: Your xorg.conf is not created by default in 11.10. It can be manually created in /etc/X11/)

you can add the line:

> Option "NvAGP" "1"

I also had to modify grub by uncommenting the line GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480 and changing it to:

> GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024

You would use your screens resolution.

There are other possible solutions that you should check out here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume

I hope these help you.

Comment: I have a similar problem to the one described above, however, I cannot find xorg.conf on my system.  At least where it is supposed to be.  I have recently installed Ubuntu 11.10.  Also, where is the `grub` file located?

Comment: Your xorg.conf is not created by default in 11.10. It can be manually created in /etc/X11/

Comment: Thanks for that.  Is there a template that you can recommend?  Note that I posted a similar question to the group a couple of days ago.  Nobody has replied as yet.