# Unable to Resume after Screen has Locked

Tags: 11.10, monitor, suspend-resume

I am not able to resume a session after the screen has been locked for a long time.  This is not a new problem.  Similar questions have been posted in the past, two of which are listed below.

[Black Screen after Screen Lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18178/black-screen-after-lock-screen)

[Screens don't work after shutting off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69295/screens-dont-work-after-shutting-off)

This problem has also been reported to Ubuntu, who have provided the following wiki link for guidance.

[DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume)

One cause of the problem that is noted in [DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume) is when the swap file is encrypted.  This will automatically happen if one decides to encrypt the `/home` directory during installation.  As I did not choose this option, I don't believe that my swap file is encrypted, however, I have encrypted the home directories of the Windows XP partition which resides on a separate drive.  Not sure if this is an issue but, how would I be able to determine whether or not the swap space partiion under Ubuntu has been encrypted?

The solution noted by @cprofitt in his/her answer to [Screens don't work after shutting down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69295/screens-dont-work-after-shutting-off) mentions modifying `xorg.conf`, and possibly `grub`.  Unfortunately, I cannot locate the `xorg.conf` file on my system.  It is not in the typical locations that one would expect to find it (e.g. `/etc/X11`).  Also, I am not certain how to modify `grub`.

As a workaround, I have turned off screen locking, however, I would really like to solve this problem.  My configuration is as follows:

```
Ubuntu 11.10
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
```

Also note that I have a KBM switch that switches between the PC and a Mac OS X laptop.  I know for a fact that this is not a problem since, I am still able to switch to my laptop when the problem occurs.  Furthermore, I have physically connected a keyboard and mouse to the PC where I have installed Ubuntu, and the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue as:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/72692/system-freezes-after-the-automatic-screen-saver-kicks-in

OR
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/882893

This is a regression bug in Gnome3 screensaver, and affects the Intel 82865G integrated graphics (or similar) devices.

BEST WORKAROUND is to replace gnome-screensaver with xscreensaver.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How can I change or install screensavers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screen-savers/64132#64132)

Comment: Thanks David.  I will give it a try tonight, and let you know how I go.  I have a similar problem on another computer, except that the screen goes blank as soon as I log in.  I intend to ask this as a separate question, however, similar issues have been posted to this group.

Comment: It worked like a charm, after I set the option `-no-splash` correctly.  Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change screensavers (not sure why you wouldn't), there's another litle workaround.

It's a bit irritating, but I found that you can fanagle the screen lock by switching between terminals (ctrl-alt-F1, ctrl-alt-F7, ctrl-alt-F6, ctrl-alt-F7) until the correct login widgets finally show up. For me it passes from background screen with status bar, to background screen, to black screen screensaver -- after which I can wake up my screen and enter my session password.

Not sure why it works, and sometimes it takes a bit longer than others, but it works consistenly, eventually, and every time.

Now, I will go install xscreensaver....