# How can I close the lid on my HP Pavilion g7 running Ubuntu 11.10 without crashing it?

Tags: 11.10, laptop, freeze, hp, screensaver

If I close the lid on my computer while it's running, it goes into sleep (hibernation?) mode. When I open back it up, the screen wakes up for a moment, then goes black. The computer is unresponsive and I must hard boot o avoid.

I've tried the following solutions. Neither worked:

1. [Edit xorg.conf](https://askubuntu.com/a/88836/46766)
2. [Replace gnomescreensaver with xscreensaver](https://askubuntu.com/a/77757/46766)

I'm not sure if this is related, but I had issues with the videocard on the laptop during install which I described here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/105792/46766

If you know of a reasonable solution, please share it with a short explanation indicating why you believe it will be effective.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just change the option for what happens when you close the lid to "Suspend" or "Do Nothing"? Is there any particular reason you need the laptop to hibernate?

Comment: @William That's what I ended up doing. I wasn't originally aware of the option.

Comment: OK. Are you okay with me making an answer as such so that the question isn't left unanswered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, start by going to the power cog in the upper-right hand corner of the screen and clicking 'System Settings".

[image]

You will see a screen like the following:

[image]

Click "Power", then change what happens when you close the lid to something other then "Hibernate".

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: The last interface is a little different on my machine (maybe I'm using a different desktop?). And "Blank Screen" was not an option. But setting it to "Do Nothing" solved the problem. Thanks for the screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, this is all I could find from Google Images as I'm not on Ubuntu right now. But it should looks similar.

Answer (score 1):

Had problems finding the "power cog" so I entered in the search field, "power" and then selected "change what power options do," then selected "nothing" for "closing the lid."

Comment: Kindly rephrase your answer to include a step-by-step procedure, adding screenshots if possible. That would make this answer easier to follow for newbies and will attract upvotes for u.. ;)